# JTextField missing and Layout wrongly placing JButtons

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I'm trying to combine afew elements into a JPanel using BorderLayout.
I have a JSlider in the center, a Name on the west if that constructor is called. Then on the east I have another panel for controlling the slider, This panel is giving all the issues.

On the east panel, I want a JTextField and two buttons stacked. I have the JTextField in the Center then a sub panel on the east that holds the buttons in the north/south to make them stacked.

When I run the program, the east panel is missing the JTextField and the buttons are acting like they are respectively set to west/east, instead of north/south.

Below is the code that I've written and looked over for a good few hours:

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/*
Made by vzybilly

Look of class:
____________________________________________________
|                    |          |            | [+] |
| <Name, if called>: | <Slider> | <Text box> |     |
|                    |          |            | [-] |
----------------------------------------------------
*/

public class AdjustableSlider extends JPanel implements javax.swing.event.ChangeListener, ActionListener{

//slider for mouse input of values
   private JSlider me;
   //text box for manual input of values
   private JTextField val;


   //Make a slider with a textbox on the right and control buttons more right for 1 movement, buttons are stacked.
   public AdjustableSlider(int min, int max, int cur, int spacing){
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
      me = new JSlider();
      me.setName("");
      me.setMinimum(min);
      me.setPaintLabels(true);
      me.setPaintTicks(true);
      me.setMajorTickSpacing(spacing);
      me.setMaximum(max);
      me.setValue(cur);
      me.addChangeListener(this);
      add(me, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      JPanel adjusters = new JPanel();
      {
         adjusters.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
         val = new JTextField(""+cur, (""+max).length());
         val.addActionListener(this);
         adjusters.add(val, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         JPanel adjustersSub = new JPanel();
         {
            adjusters.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            JButton up = new JButton("+");
            up.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener(){
                     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        me.setValue(me.getValue()+1);}});
            JButton down = new JButton("-");
            down.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener(){
                     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        me.setValue(me.getValue()-1);}});
            adjustersSub.add(up, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            adjustersSub.add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         }
         adjusters.add(adjustersSub, BorderLayout.EAST);
      }
      add(adjusters, BorderLayout.EAST);
   }

   //add a name label to the Slider.
   public AdjustableSlider(int min, int max, int cur, int spacing, String name){
      this(min, max, cur, spacing);
      add(new JLabel(name+":"), BorderLayout.WEST);}


      //slider updated, reflect.
   public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent e){
      System.out.println("Slid: " + me.getValue());
      val.setText(""+me.getValue());}

      //textbox updated, reflect.
   public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
      System.out.println("Type: " + val.getText());
      try{int t = Integer.parseInt(val.getText());
         if(me.getValue()!=t) me.setValue(t);}
      catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}}


      //get the current value of this slider
   public int get(){
      return me.getValue();}
}
```

I'm just starting this program so my JFrame is pretty bare:

```
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  frame.setTitle("Frame");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  //frame.setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
  frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
  JPanel sliders = new JPanel();
  {
     sliders.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
  }
  JPanel controls = new JPanel();
  {
     controls.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
     volume = new AdjustableSlider(0, 100, 90, 10, "Volume");
     controls.add(volume, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }
  frame.add(sliders, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  frame.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
```

Edit: I have made the corrections and fixed afew errors involving the text field updating and being updated, the new code is below.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

/*
Made by vzybilly

Look of class:
____________________________________________________
|                    |          |            | [+] |
| <Name, if called>: | <Slider> | <Text box> |     |
|                    |          |            | [-] |
----------------------------------------------------
*/

public class AdjustableSlider extends JPanel{

//slider for mouse input of values
   private JSlider me;
   //text box for manual input of values
   private JTextField val;


   //Make a slider with a textbox on the right and control buttons more right for 1 movement, buttons are stacked.
   public AdjustableSlider(int min, int max, int cur, int spacing){
      setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
      me = new JSlider();
      me.setName("");
      me.setMinimum(min);
      me.setPaintLabels(true);
      me.setPaintTicks(true);
      me.setMajorTickSpacing(spacing);
      me.setMaximum(max);
      me.setValue(cur);
      me.addChangeListener(
            new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener(){
               public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent e){
                  try{
                     if(val.getText().length()<1||Integer.parseInt(val.getText())!=me.getValue())
                        val.setText(""+me.getValue());}
                  catch(NumberFormatException nfe){val.setText(""+me.getValue());}}});
      add(me, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      JPanel adjusters = new JPanel();
      {
         adjusters.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
         val = new JTextField(""+cur, (""+max).length());
         val.addCaretListener(
               new javax.swing.event.CaretListener(){
                  public void caretUpdate(javax.swing.event.CaretEvent ce){
                     try{int t = Integer.parseInt(val.getText());
                        if(me.getValue()!=t) me.setValue(t);}
                     catch(NumberFormatException nfe){/*System.out.println("null input to box");*/}
                     catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}}});
         adjusters.add(val, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         JPanel adjustersSub = new JPanel();
         {
            adjustersSub.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            JButton up = new JButton("+");
            up.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener(){
                     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        me.setValue(me.getValue()+1);}});
            JButton down = new JButton("-");
            down.addActionListener(
                  new ActionListener(){
                     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        me.setValue(me.getValue()-1);}});
            adjustersSub.add(up, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            adjustersSub.add(down, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
         }
         adjusters.add(adjustersSub, BorderLayout.EAST);
      }
      add(adjusters, BorderLayout.EAST);
   }

   //add a name label to the Slider.
   public AdjustableSlider(int min, int max, int cur, int spacing, String name){
      this(min, max, cur, spacing);
      add(new JLabel(name+":"), BorderLayout.WEST);}


      //get the current value of this slider
   public int get(){
      return me.getValue();}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a typo issue, your problem is after instantiating `adjustersSub` you re-defined the layout for `adjusters` instead

```
49c49
<             adjusters.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
---
>             adjustersSub.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
```

Comment: thanks, I feel quite stupid right now... I'll see if I can't upload the edits when I get internet again...